# How do i setup exim4 to deliver email to my cyrus (sasl) and forward a copy of them to gmail?

Tags: debian, exim, cyrus

Currently, exim4 forwards all email at my domains to my gmail account. (And my brothers' to their accounts.) Using a split configuration, (/etc/exim4/conf.d/routers/350_exim4-config_vdom_aliases) uses (domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual), where i have a number of files, one per domain/sub-domain, with (* : ...@gmail.com) as the content. (It's actually symlinked to a file with those contents.) Now, i have Cyrus and Squirrelmail installed, and i want to host my email locally, though still forward a copy of the emails to gmail.

How do i setup exim4 to deliver email to my cyrus (sasl) and forward a copy of them to gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the structure of your config I can't say for certain how you're doing things, there's a lot of ways people can have their setup configured with Exim. Saying that, you should be able to accomplish this with the `unseen` option for routers.

You can find details in the manual under `15. Generic options for routers`:

```
Setting the unseen option has a similar effect to the unseen command qualifier
in filter files. It can be used to cause copies of messages to be delivered to
some other destination, while also carrying out a normal delivery. In effect,
the current address is made into a “parent” that has two children – one that
is delivered as specified by this router, and a clone that goes on to be routed
further. For this reason, unseen may not be combined with the one_time option
in a redirect router.
```

Comment: Thanx. That definitely looks like the option. Currently, the router is virtual hosts: vdom_aliases:
      driver = redirect
      allow_defer
      allow_fail
      domains = dsearch;/etc/exim4/virtual
      data = ${expand:${lookup{$local_part}lsearch*@{/etc/exim4/virtual/$domain}}}
      retry_use_local_part
      pipe_transport   = address_pipe
      file_transport   = address_file

Comment: That `${expand:}` wrapper is probably a security glitch waiting to bite and should be unneeded. Also, with that driver, you should be able to just make the value of the entry be a colon-separated list of email addresses, where one is the same as the original address. Exim will avoid expanding the same value twice, so there's no loop.